# Python Dataframe Merge: string capitalization issue

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, merge

When I try to merge two difference data-sets based on the values of a column, I notice that the column values from the two sheets will match correctly if the capitalization is the same.  However, Python will not be able to identify the corresponding value for df1 from df2 if the capitalization is different, even though the string is the same.

Is there anyway to do this without altering the content of the datasets?

```
merged_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['column1'], how = 'left')
merged_df.drop_duplicates(keep='first', inplace=True)
merged_df.to_csv('report.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: If the capitalization is different, the strings are *not* the same.  Why don't you just normalize the capitalization

Comment: You can use string method `str.lower()` if you want to effectively ignore capitalization in your comparisons. But yes, `'ThisString'!='thisstring'`

Comment: You can use `left_on` and `right_on`

Comment: Is there any way I can implement this in a merge statement?

Answer (score 3):

Normalize your strings *before* your merge via [`pd.Series.str.lower`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.lower.html). If, for some reason, you don't wish to change your original dataframes, you can use [`pd.DataFrame.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
merged_df = pd.merge(df1.assign(column1=df1['column1'].str.lower()),
                     df2.assign(column1=df2['column1'].str.lower()),
                     on='column1', how='left')
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy to understand approach,

```
df1['column1']=df1['column1'].str.lower()
df2['column2']=df2['column2'].str.lower()
```

Then continue with your code.

Comment: I will go this route, thanks.  I was just wondering if there was anyway to do this without altering the content of the datasets.

Comment: @ Ashutosh..  `df2['column1']=df2['column1'].str.lower()` , just change that second occurence for the sake or difference,